# Couchbase is there any limit of documents in a bucket?

Tags: limit, document, couchbase

is there any limit of documents in a bucket?

We have a scenario of loading 1.8million documents, that was storing successfuly only upto 1.5m.

Another issue, When we write a basic view, its resulting into only 1535results, though more results (almost all) possible.

Through .net client also, we have verified that GetView is returning only 1535.

again, any limitation on number of documents and also on View results?

Please guide us with any resources, links - if possible.

thanks

Comment: Make sure all your documents are small enough to fit. I remember reading somewhere that documents are limited to 25mb.

Comment: The limit for a Couchbase Bucket is 20MB. The memcached bucket is 1MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couchbase does not have any limit on the numbers of document (as soon  as you have enough memory for the keys and disk for the document)

It looks like your problem is not a "size" issue but the way you are using the views.

Could you confirm that your view us publish in "production"?

If you still use the view in development you will have only a subset of the document except if you execute the query with full_set=true.

Comment: Once the documents are in PROD mode, the number of documents was coming as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the documents have been written to disk or is that queue not processed? If not, they will not be indexed.

> "Once the document has been persisted to disk, the document can be
>   indexed by the view mechanism." - http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-datastore-indexseq.html

Have you tried executing the query against the view and controlling the `Stale` flag?

```
var view = client.GetView("foo","bar").Stale(StaleMode.False);
```

More info:

- http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-writing-stale.html
- http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/creating-views-from-sdk.html